# Check a given string is a math function or not in R

Tags: regex, r, math

I have an expression like this `abs(iodlin_vod2*1e6)/(array*nfin*nrx*nfinger*weff)`. My code splits this expression using `strsplit`. Now,  from this result, I should check each word whether it is a math function, if it is not I should perform some operation.
I am stuck at checking the word if it is math function or not. Can someone please help.

Qsn edited:
This is result of `strsplit`

```
sstemp
[1] "abs"          "iodlin_vod2 " " 1e+06"       "array "       " nfin "       
" nrx "       
[7] " nfinger "    " weff"
```

I want to eliminate `abs` and `1e+06` from further operations in my code.

Comment: wouldn't every string of characters followed by `(` be a "math function" in your case. please add your code and examples; your question is vague

Comment: Could you provide the output of the strsplit operation? I can help you construct a regex, but I'm less familiar with R. It'd be helpful if you provided a list of the "math functions" (perhaps a link to the documentation) and the result of this `strsplit` operation on `abs(str1*1e6)/(str2*str3)`.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check

Comment: There are 4 functions that get called in your example expression. I see only one of those in your `strsplit` output. You should parse the expression and analyze the call tree.

Comment: str1, str2, str3 are column names of data frame. Now I have added real column names in the question. Your solution helped

Comment: After an answer has been posted, it's probably best to only change your example in ways that keep the answer valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's look at the call tree:

```
ttt <- "abs(str1*1e6)/(str2*str3)"
library(pryr)
call_tree(parse(text=ttt))
#\- ()
#  \- `/
#  \- ()
#    \- `abs
#    \- ()
#      \- `*
#      \- `str1
#      \-  1e+06
#  \- ()
#    \- `(
#    \- ()
#      \- `*
#      \- `str2
#      \- `str3
```

See also [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#structure-of-expressions).

Now let's create this in a machine usable format and clean up a bit:

```
test <- gsub("\\\\\\-|\\s*|`", "",
          unlist(
            strsplit(
              vapply(parse(text = ttt), pryr:::tree, 
                     character(1), width = getOption("width")), 
            "\\n")
          )
        )
#[1] "()"    "/"     "()"    "abs"   "()"    "*"     "str1"  "1e+06" "()"    "("     "()"    "*"     "str2"  "str3"
```

Then we can test:

```
vapply(test, function(x) is.function(tryCatch(getFunction(x), error = function(cond) NA)), logical(1))
#   ()     /    ()   abs    ()     *  str1 1e+06    ()     (    ()     *  str2  str3 
#FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

As you see, there are four different functions: `/`, `abs`, `*`, and `(` in this expression.

This solution will fail if you have a non-function object with a function name in your expression.

Comment: This solution helped.